# Making migrations for app models moved to another directory that's not their default creation directory

Tags: python-3.x, django, makemigrations

This is my folder structure

```
backend
  server
  apps          # directory I created
    endpoints   # my app
```

In settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS[
   .......
   'apps.endpoint'
  ]
```

When I run python3 manage.py make migrations
I'm receiving a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'endpoints'

Comment: what is your app name that you create using this command `python manage.py startapp AppName`